# Updating listview in one fragment with data from another fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

Ok, so ive spend two days on this and I have tried everything under the sun and Google :L

Basically, if I  add or delete something from my server, I want to update my listview which is in mylistfragment from my detailfragment to reflect the changes on the server. The changes have occur ed through clicking either a delete or add button in my detail fragment.

I have a callback method which has everything that I need to repopulate the  listview with I just cant seem to get the listview to update.

Any help would  be much appreciated.

My callback code is as follows :

```
  public final Handler myCallBackAll = new Handler() {
  @Override
     public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
       ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
   if (msg.obj == "No Response") {
     TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
     tv2.setText("No Response. Please check your internet connection");
     tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     lv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  } else {
    Beer beers = new Beer();
    ArrayAdapter<Beer> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Beer>(
    getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,(List)msg.obj);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapterNew);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
};
```

It doesnt throw any errors just doesnt work

How my callback is called is here

```
if (isBound) {
 myBinder.getAllBeer(myCallBackAll);
}
```

Its a bounded service I have to use, a stipulation of the project. All this code works, just mylistview wont update

Comment: Can you paste the code you have in the callback, and also how you are executing that callback?

Comment: code added as requested. Thanks

Comment: Use `String.equals()` to test `String` equality.

Comment: what exactly would that be testing for tho, my code works except for the updating/refreshing of the listview on the other fragment

Comment: Stephen, I have updated my answer after seeing your code.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that and no luck, commented on post below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured it out, may not be the best approach but it does work, i had declare my listview as a static variable in my main activity, i then reference this variable in both fragments and it works a treat :P

Answer (score 1):

You say that you have already have the callback set up, so I am assuming the callback is being fired accordingly. If that is the case, make sure you update the data source (Array, List, etc) you are using in your adapter to reflect the changes you made in detailfragment.

Also, don't forget that every time you add, edit, delete data from your adapter's data source, you must call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to tell the adapter something in your data changed.

**EDIT**

Try creating your handler this way instead: `public final Handler myCallBackAll = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`

notifyDataSetChanged() must be executed on the main UI thread. When you create a new handler it will execute on its own thread, so you need to make sure it does execute on the UI thread. Take a look at [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html#Handler) for more information

Comment: tried this, still not working and no errors. I have debugged the code and I can see that the code update the adapter fires, but the adapter just doesnt update

Comment: Try adding this `arrayAdapter.clear();` before creating the new adapter (use the correct adapter name, I'm assuming its also called arrayAdapter).

Comment: finally figured it out, may not be the best approach but it does work, i had declare my listview as a static variable in my main activity, i then reference this variable in both fragments and it works a treat :P